# groupby rows based on substring and assign column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I got two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X', '2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX', '2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X', '2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324', '2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X'], 'label':[ 0,0,0,0,0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['BID_-324', 'BID_123', 'BID_-398'], 'label':[1,1,2]})
```

I want to group the rows of `df1` based on the column `Id` in `df2` corresponding to which `Id` is present in `df1` `A` column as a substring.  I also want to change the column `label` in `df1` to the correspnding value of `df2` based on the same condition. I also need a group identifier to check which group they are in.

My expected output for the above input is

```
df
   gid                                       A  label
0    1     2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X      1
1    1       2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324      1
2    2     2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX      1
3    2      2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X      1
4    3  2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X      2
```

Here `gid` is the group identifier, and within each group I want the rows to appear in the same sequence as it appears in the original file. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

# Recreating your data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X', 
'2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX', 
'2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X', 
'2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324', 
'2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X'], 'label':[ 0,0,0,0,0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['BID_-324', 'BID_123', 'BID_-398'], 'label':[1,1,2]})


# We want to use the index in a query, so we can use the approach given here
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812087/groupby-rows-based-on-substring-and-assign-column-value/63812344?noredirect=1#comment112845267_63812344
df2.index.rename('row_idx', inplace=True)


# Select using like with the % wildcard
df_res = ps.sqldf("""select df2.row_idx +1 gid, df1.A, df2.label 
                     from df1
                      inner join df2
                       on df1.A like '%' || df2.id || '%' 
                      order by df2.row_idx  """, locals())
print(df_res)
```

The result is

```
   gid                                       A  label
0    1     2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X      1
1    1       2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324      1
2    2     2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX      1
3    2      2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X      1
4    3  2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X      2
```

Discussion:

You'll notice that you have to indicate that you want to use the index in a query
by renaming it.
Now that you have the index of df2 available, you can sort by that as well.

Comment: sorry.  There was an error in the intended output.  grouping should be based on the substring.  I corrected the question to reflect it. Can you check it ?

Comment: @Shew: I have updated my answer now that you explained how gid should be derived.

Comment: @Shew: If this solution satisfies your requirements, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to extract the BID* Ids using `str.extract` to a new column and then merge the 2 DataFrames using `pandas.merge`:

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1['Id'] = df1['A'].str.extract('(BID[\_\-0-9]*)')
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Id']).drop(columns=['Id', 'label_x']).rename(columns={'label_y': 'label', 'index': 'gid'})
df['gid'] = df['gid'] + 1
print(df)

                                        A  gid  label
0     2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X    1      1
1       2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324    1      1
2     2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX    2      1
3      2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X    2      1
4  2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X    3      2
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add an extra column for group id.  There was an error in the intended output. I corrected it.